# Question about websocket and loction.replace

Tags: javascript, websocket, deno

I try to use Deno ws to reload the document, but it will throw an error after second reload
`Uncaught ConnectionReset: Socket has already been closed throw new Deno.errors.ConnectionReset("Socket has already been closed");`

```js
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws")
    ws.onopen = function () {
      ws.send('ws open')
      console.log('ws open');
    }
    ws.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      if (e.data === 'fileUpdate') {
        // ws.send('close')
        location.replace(location.href);
      }
    })
```

seem `location.replace(location.href)` raise an error
any solution?

Comment: Without the server side code, it's impossible to reproduce. Please show your Deno code. Because it looks like you're trying to close the socket twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is happening because you're sending a message **after** the socket is closed.

When you do: `location.replace(location.href);` the page is refreshed and the current socket is closed.

You can either catch the error, or check for `ws.isClosed` before sending the message.

```js
for await (const e of ws) {
  if (e === 'close') {
    ob.remove("fileUpdate")
    continue
  }
  ob.on("fileUpdate", () => {
    console.log('sending')
    if(!ws.isClosed)
       ws.send("fileUpdate")
  })
}
```

While that will fix the error, it won't fix the cause. Your `ob.on('fileUpdate')` event is firing **after** the socket is closed. You should clear that listener on the WebSocket close event, you can do that using `ws.isWebSocketCloseEvent`

```js
import { acceptWebSocket, isWebSocketCloseEvent } from "https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/ws/mod.ts";
/* ... */
for await (const e of ws) {
  if(isWebSocketCloseEvent(e) || e === 'close') {
    // clear listeners here
    ob.remove("fileUpdate")
    // if e === 'close' you may want to close the socket
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is Deno code :

```js
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc/mod.ts"; 
import { acceptWebSocket } from "https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/ws/mod.ts";
new Application()
  .file("/", "./index.html")
  .file("/module.js", "./module.js")
  // .file("sw.js", "ServiceWorker.js")

  .get('/ws', async (c: any) => {
    const { conn, headers, r: bufReader, w: bufWriter } = c.request;
    const ws = await acceptWebSocket({
      conn,
      headers,
      bufReader,
      bufWriter,
    });
    for await (const e of ws) {
      if (e === 'close') {
        ob.remove("fileUpdate")
        continue
      }
      ob.on("fileUpdate", () => {
        ws.send("fileUpdate")
      })
    }
  })
  .start({ port: 8080 })
```

`ob` like this :

```js
class Ob {
  private list: ObList[] = []
  send(event: string) {
    this.list.forEach((e: ObList) => {
      if (e.event === event) {
        e.cb && e.cb()
      }
    })
  }
  on(event: string, cb: Function) {
    this.list.push({ event, cb })
  }
  remove(event:string){
    this.list=this.list.filter((e:ObList)=>{
      return e.event!==event
    })
  }
}
```

the framework is [abc](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/x/abc/mod.ts)

Comment: That code does not work. Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's very hard to help you.

Comment: i use  ESmodule in script ,and if i don't reload .it will be work

Comment: That code does not compile, show your full server code that we can run. Send me a `gist` and I'll check it out, or update it here

Comment: here is [repository](https://github.com/wk989898/deno-vue-module)

Comment: check my answer. Btw you should update your **question** with the code, instead of posting the code as an answer (unless it's actually an answer)

Comment: i'm sorry,this is first question i ask and i don't know how update my question. do i need delete it?

Comment: No worries I was explaining for the future. My recommendation is to edit your question with that code. Just hit `edit` and add it :)